# How to set a starting page in an ionic app?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I want to set the Registration.html page as my starting page when I enter 'ionic serve' on command prompt.

Here is my code of app.js, index.html & Registration.html

What changes should be made to achieve the result?

app.js:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
    .state('Registration', {
        url: '/Registration',
        templateUrl: 'templates/Registration.html'
        controller: 'RegistrationController'
    })
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Registration');
})
```

index.html:

```
 <body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Demo</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Registration.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Registration">
<ion-content class="padding">
    <h1>Welcome !</h1>
    <h1>Please Sign in To Connect</h1>
    <div class="list">
        <button class="button ion-social-linkedin button-positive button-block" >Connect using LinkedIn</button>
        <button class="button ion-social-google button-positive button-block" >Connect using Google</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: When you run `ionic serve` which is the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index.html between body tags just place `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` Remove everything else...

Comment: Added:    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
     <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view> 
    </ion-nav-view>
Now working fine..

Answer (score 0):

If you use state app, try this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/Registration');
```

Comment: the change didn't work.. still showing contents fom the index.html page